# GAS Add-on, onOpen function running continuously?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have two Google Sheets add-ons that I have written for private use by users in my domain. Both add-ons use the `onOpen` function to generate a menu in Sheets. Both are written with the standard format provided in the [Google Developers documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus). An example of the code for the menu is below. Note that no triggers are installed in any portion of my script.

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createAddonMenu()
    .addItem('1️⃣ Authorize', 'authFunction')
    .addItem('2️⃣ Format Sheet', 'ResetDataHTML')
    .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('3️⃣ Type & Clean Up')
      .addItem('️ Set Trip type', 'setTripType')
      .addItem('️ Remove & Set Count', 'deleteNoTrans'))
    .addItem('4️⃣  Email to Transportation', 'emailSheetNote')
  .addToUi();
  return;
}
```

The add-ons both function properly. The "problem" I am noticing is when viewing the Execution Logs in the new IDE. For one add-on the `onOpen` function is constantly running/completing at an interval of about 1-3 seconds. The other add-on seems to run the `onOpen` function at intervals of about 20-30 minutes. **My question is, "why would these add-ons continue to run the `onOpen` function?** Am I noticing *normal behavior* or is this *abnormal*? (I have not noticed this behavior with any other script that uses the `onOpen` function.)

Thank you to anyone that might have some insight as to my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Every time you or the other users visit or refresh the sheet, it does trigger the `onOpen` trigger thus possibly showing in your execution logs multiple times. Don't worry about it as that is entirely normal.

Comment: Thanks, NaziA. The use should be minimal right now and it's not a heavily used app to begin with which is why I was a little surprised. I'll keep my eye on the logs to see if they change.

Comment: No Problem @PaulMurray. If we answered your question, please click the accept button.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Will do, @NaziA. I was waiting a moment to see with there were any other comments. :)